# Issue regarding SQL Server 2005 CTE & FOR XML PATH('') usage

Tags: sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I have generated the month number through a CTE and try to generate output like 
`1,2,3,....30,31` through using `for xml` but I'm getting an error

Here is my full script

```
;With CTEMonth As 
(Select 1 As Number
Union All
Select m.Number + 1 As Number
From CTEMonth m
Where m.Number <=30)  

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + m.Number
                    from CTEMonth m 
                    order by m.Number
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
print @cols
```

What is wrong in my SQL? Please guide. thanks

Comment: Please provide first! Please give us the full and complete error message - after all, we can neither see your screen, nor read your mind (yet) - so you'll need to show us what's happening....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the DECLARE to *before* the CTE.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

;With CTEMonth As 
(Select 1 As Number
Union All
Select m.Number + 1 As Number
From CTEMonth m
Where m.Number <=30)  
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + m.Number
                    from CTEMonth m 
                    order by m.Number
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value(N'./text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

print @cols;
```

Also, a recursive CTE is not the most efficient way to generate a set - see [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1), [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-2) and [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-3) for better alternatives, such as a numbers table or a calendar table.

Comment: so can u tell me what would be the best approach for generating set of number with example. thanks

Comment: @Thomas did you not see any of the examples in the links I provided?